# CSS image fixed Height dynamic Width

Tags: html, css

I have a set of different images that I want to line up on a horizontal row.
I want to set the height but keep the correct width. (dynamic width)

The problem is that the width is the same for all pictures.

Any ideas?

This is my markup and style:

```
<div class="jumbo">
   <ul>
      <li><img src="picture1.jpg" /></li>
      <li><img src="picture2.jpg" /></li>
      <li><img src="picture3.jpg" /></li>
   </ul>
</div>

.jumbo ul {
  height: 430px;
  width: 20000px;
  margin-top:10px;
  /*border: 2px solid red;*/
}
.jumbo li {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 70px;
}

.jumbo img {
    max-height:430px;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Your markup seems to be working fine for me (http://jsfiddle.net/3WPm2/2/) Are you sure your images just don't all have the same aspect ratio?

Comment: The accepted answer didn't work for me, but this was helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40428690/image-with-fixed-height-width-auto-and-keep-ratio

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Two ways to get proportional sizing. Either set the container (in your case ul) to a fixed height and then set the image height to 100% - don't state a width - the width will then be proportional to the height (that's what you want, right?). Alternatively, just set the image height, and leave the width unstated - again, the width will be proportional.