# image with fixed height, width auto and keep ratio

Tags: html, css

I have a responsive `ul` list, where each `li` is 50% of `ul` width.
In each `li`, I have an image. I want to have a fixed height and a 100% width, keeping the ratio of the image (by zooming for instance). How can I do this please?

```css
ul {
  width: 100%
}
li {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
li img {
  height: 262px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="aa.jpg">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="bb.jpg">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Try playing around with max-height and max-width alongside height and width

Comment: So the `li` needs to be fixed height and `overflow: hidden`. Then the image inside is simply `width: 100%`

Comment: your li img are missing can't make you a snipped demo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment you can either use

```
li {
overflow: hidden;
height: 262px; 
}
li img {
width: 100%;
}
```

or you can set the image as background

```
li {
height: 262px;
background: url(image.png) center center no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's perfect reenleedr !

Answer (score 0):

You need to omit stating the width of the image. This way the height of the image supplied will be resized to your desired 262px height and its corresponding width will automatically size down to its corresponding aspect ratio of the original.

```
ul {
  width: 100%
}
li {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
li img {
  height: 262px;
}
```